# How to properly destroy a Spring configuration class

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

**Case 1**

Let's consider the following Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConf1 {

    @Bean
    public Foo getFoo() {
        // Foo class is defined as part of an external lib.
        return new Foo();
    }

    @Bean
    public Bar getBar() {
        return new Bar(getFoo());
    } 

 }
```

For some reasons, I need to invoke a `Foo`'s method (i.e. `myFoo.shutdown();`) when `MyConf1` is destroyed.
Is there any way to perform this operation without retrieving the bean instance directly from the application context (via `ApplicationContext.getBean()`)?

**Case 2**

Again, let's consider a second Spring configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConf2 {

    @Bean
    public ScheduledJob scheduledJob() {
        Timer jobTimer = new Timer(true);
        return new ScheduledJob(jobTimer);
    }

 }
```

This time, I need to invoke `jobTimer.cancel()` before destroying `MyConf2`. Indeed, I can instantiate `jobTimer` outside `scheduledJob()`, or making it a method's parameter, as `scheduledJob(Timer jobTimer)`.
It will then be possible to define a proper destroyer method for `MyConf2`. However, I would like to know if there are other ways to proceed.

Any good suggestion?

**Note:** `Foo`, `Bar`, `Timer`, `ScheduledJob` classes are defined externally. Thus, there is no possibility to explicitly define an inner destroy method. As assumption, I can modify only `MyConf1` and `MyConf2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest defining a `destroy()` method (annotated with `@PreDestroy`) in `Foo` class

Similarly, modify `ScheduledJob` class like

```
public class ScheduledJob {

    private Timer timer;

    public ScheduledJob(Timer timer){
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy(){
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

And add `destroyMethod` param in `@Bean`

```
@Configuration
public class MyConf2 {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
    public ScheduledJob scheduledJob() {
        Timer jobTimer = new Timer(true);
        return new ScheduledJob(jobTimer);
    }

}
```

Comment: The `Foo` and `ScheduledJob` classes are supposed to be defined externally, thus no possibility to explicitly define a destroy method.

Comment: HI @vdenotaris.  I am unsure if this solve your problem. So the @PostConstrcut and @Predestory are just the short forms of having the methods predefined in the POJO class rather than in the Configuration class. So the other way of explicitly using the destroy method is to implement the code like this.  `@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    public ScheduledJob scheduledJob() {
        Timer jobTimer = new Timer(true);
         timer.close(); return new ScheduledJob(jobTimer);
    }`

Comment: We no need `@PreDestroy` if using `destroyMethod`

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following page http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/48426-postconstruct-and-predestroy-in-javaconfig

DisposableBean should help you with case #1.

Comment: Please read carefully my question. The thread you mentioned just covers the second case, and I already explained how the `destroy` method can be used. However, as said, I am looking for other approaches, if indeed possible (with related explanations).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor` interface that can adds a before-destruction callback when the bean is destroy.In that interface,the method `postProcessBeforeDestruction` is do that,see the following:

```
@Override
public void postProcessBeforeDestruction(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("before destory:"+bean);
}

@Override
public boolean requiresDestruction(Object bean) {
    return true;
}
```

Pay attention to that the method `requiresDestruction` should return true,otherwise the method `postProcessBeforeDestruction` will not call when bean should destroy.

And i have a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:application-main.xml");
    applicationContext.registerShutdownHook();
}
```

The `postProcessBeforeDestruction` really call when the bean is destroy.The output is :

```
before destory:com.zhuyiren.spring.learn.util.Handler@55141def
before destory:com.zhuyiren.spring.learn.controller.TestControleler@47eaca72
before destory:com.zhuyiren.spring.learn.service.impl.TestServiceImpl@7b2bbc3
before destory:com.zhuyiren.spring.learn.service.impl.TwoServiceImpl@48f2bd5b
before destory:com.zhuyiren.spring.learn.controller.ConverConroller@72967906
before destory:org.springframework.context.event.DefaultEventListenerFactory@1a482e36
before destory:org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor@77fbd92c
```

Comment: This approach is not very clear for me. As said, I have no chance to extend the behaviours of `Foo`, `ScheduledJob` and `Timer` (at least, without using a proper design pattern like *Adapter*). Basically the only classes that I can directly modify are `MyConf1` and `MyConf2`.

Comment: Not extend,just create a new class for implement above interface,and make a bean of that class in the application, using `Component` annotation or config that bean  in the xml file.That bean just register a callback in the application,the application will call these method for each bean when destroy.

Comment: Sorry, when I said *extend the behaviours* I did't mean *extend a class*, just to clarify this point. :) However, I have to assume to use the given classes just as they are, without any wrapping (I know, I am making it hard on purpose).

Comment: this approach should fit your use case. I saw an example of `BeanPostProcessor` at http://arecordon.blogspot.in/p/spring-bean-post-processor.html to understand what @dabaicai mean.  Since `ScheduledJob` is externally supplied class, and if it exposes canceling timer, you can cancel the timer in `postProcessBeforeDestruction` method by checking if bean is `instanceof ScheduledJob` (i know its not elegant solution).